# Is it possible to customize plotly rangeslider in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, rangeslider

Quick note: I have also posted this question on the [R Studio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/select-a-range-with-plotly-slider/93592).

I am trying to modify a plotly slider to make it a rangeslider similar to the one here: [image].

The problem with the `rangeslider()` function is that instead of a rangeslider like the one in the image it produces one that is essentially a subplot of the main plot:

```
dat<- data.frame(y=rnorm(366, mean=100, sd=50),
                 x=seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by="days"))
p1<- dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("") + ylab("") 
ggplotly(p1, tooltip="x", dynamicTicks = TRUE) %>% rangeslider()
```

[image].

I have managed to get a slider more similar to the one I want in style using `frame =` in ggplot's aesthetics, however the resulting slider only selects one value at a time instead of a range of them:

```
dat<- data.frame(y=rnorm(366, mean=100, sd=50),
                 x=seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), by="days"))
p1<- dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y, frame=as.character(x))) +
  geom_col(position="dodge2") +
  theme_minimal() +
  xlab("") + ylab("") 
ggplotly(p1, tooltip="x")
```

[image].

Is it possible to create a rangeslider in the style I want with plotly?. I would be hugely thankful for any advice on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the built-in Plotly sliders only have one "handle" and so cannot express a range.

Comment: I have devised a kind of solution using crosstalk's filter_slider() (https://rpubs.com/LucasT/715872), however this does not zoom in to the graph when the range is selected in the same way range_slider() does.

Comment: And how about connectin the rangeslider form Shiny to a plotly plot? Is that doable? See my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392086/connect-rangeslider-r-shiny-to-plotly-plot